# Puppeteer PDF, footer and content on the same line?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, puppeteer

Not sure if I'm doing this the right way, but the problem I'm trying to solve is to have a page counter on every page (using puppeteer footerTemplate), and on the last page, a standard disclaimer produced via the regular html.

As can be seen in the below screenshot, the brown border is from the html tag. The blue border from my footer and the black border is from the footerTemplate.

This is the current code. I thought that using a transparent background might work, but no luck so far.

Open to other suggestions as well, but everything I tried so far have failed due to the disclaimer should only be on the last page.

```
const page = await browser.newPage()
await page.setContent(html, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })
await page.evaluate(() => document.body.style.background = 'transparent');

const buffer = await page.pdf({
  format: 'A4',
  displayHeaderFooter: true,
  headerTemplate: '<span></span>',
  footerTemplate: '<footer html code>',
  printBackground: true,
  omitBackground: true,
  margin: {
    top: '40px',
    bottom: '40px',
    left: '50px',
    right: '50px',
  }
})
```

[image: Example problem]

Comment: I'm struggling with this - I want puppeteer to take multiple lines, however they seem to get merged into one line, I even tried a table but didnt work

Comment: I more or less gave up on this. Haven't tried multiple lines in the footer, but it works fine when using it in the header.